Google Workspace ETL
We are planning a Google Workspace archive. We are trying to back up everything, including emails, files in Google Drive, and Admin console reports.
We are thinking of using Python and Airflow to build an ETL pipeline to store data on AWS. This is the first time that we are building a big pipeline. Do you have any suggestion to accomplish this report?
Thanks!
